# How to express "silly" in German?

Tags: single-word-request, adjective

The English word "silly" has a multitude of meanings. Is there a single German word that would work as a translation for "silly" the following example sentences? If not, which word should I use in each case?

> He keeps calling you these silly names. (*playful*)
>
> Your silly husband is participating in the brezel marathon. (*irresponsible*)
>
> That silly man will never graduate. (*unintelligent*)
>
> Parse HTML with regex? That's a silly idea! (*foolish*)

"Blöd", "dumm" and "doof" feel too insulting to fit the first two senses.

Comment: @cos I've never heard of that. Are you thinking of "frech" (cheeky)?

Comment: @Cos Perhaps you'd like to clarify what you're trying to say here, as it seems quite offensive and nonesensical to me at the moment.

Comment: Not to say... silly?

Comment: What about "unsinnig"?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"albern" could fit, but feels a bit outdated.

Comment: I don't think "albern" is outdated. Sei doch nicht albern!

Comment: Don't think so either. I use it quite often, actually. However, it fits only with sentence #1 and #4. #2 wouldn't really work and #3 doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: 'Albern' fits and is quite universal - definitely not outdated!

Comment: http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_Ministerium_für_alberne_Gänge

Answer (score 9):

Indeed such a universal word like silly is badly missing in German. Each of your examples would be put in other words (only given here as examples - there are many other variants)

> He keeps calling you these silly names. (playful)

*"albern"*

> Your silly husband is participating in the brezel marathon. (irresponsible)

*"leichtsinnig"*

> That silly man will never graduate. (unintelligent)

*"einfältig"*

> Parse HTML with regex? That's a silly idea! (foolish)

*"blöd"*

Answer (score 6):

In der Schweiz wird an dieser Stelle oft 'lustig' benutzt. Das Wort bekommt in einem bestimmten Kontext die Konnotation von 'silly'.

> You silly guy, you ate up all the
>   cookies!?
>
> Du bisch no ne luschtige, hesch eifach
>   aui Güezli ufg'ässe?!
>
> Du bist mir noch ein lustiger Kerl,
>   hast die Kekse einfach weggeputzt.

Aber das funktioniert lange nicht für alle Sätze in der Frage.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use *silly* in a more playful, less insulting way than *blöd* or *doof*, how about

- *töricht* (foolish, simple, loses its weight slightly because it's old fashioned)

  or
- *dümmlich* (roughly translates to something like 'slightly idiotic')

Of course, just like 'silly', you can *not* rely on those words being understood "correctly".

Comment: Thanks. Could I say "Dein törichter/dümmlicher Mann hat zu viele Brezeln gegessen." without getting anyone offended?

Comment: Well, no... or only if you have a really nice smile. You're quite right in assuming that there is no comparable equivalent to 'silly'

Comment: Actually, I can't think of a single polite way to translate the Brezel sentence into German. I would actually recommend just to leave out the "silly" and instead add a reproachful undertone and roll your eyes ("Dein Mann nimmt am Brezel-Marathon teil...!!!").

Comment: @ladybug Do you think "your silly husband" is a polite expression in English? If not: why trying to translate it in a polite way?

Answer (score 3):

How come nobody suggested *dämlich*? It fits in all the examples too.

edit:
*Dämlich* has the (to me at least) literal connotation of "like a foolish old lady", which is unkind to old ladies, I know. Entirely subjectively I would say it is probably just a tick more negative than *albern*, slightly in the direction of "anyone who does this must be a bit stupid".

Anyway:

```
He keeps calling you these silly names. (playful)
```

*dämliche Namen*, perhaps he's trying to make you look stupid, or he's making himself look stupid.

```
Your silly husband is participating in the brezel marathon. (irresponsible)
```

*Dämlich* is exactly right here. He's daft to contemplate it.

```
That silly man will never graduate. (unintelligent)
```

This isn't something you would say in English either, I think, but here *dämlich* could mean "too scatty" or "too unorganised".

```
Parse HTML with regex? That's a silly idea! (foolish)
```

Now here *dämlich* is right, meaning "it's a stupid thing to try".

*Dämlich* is used a lot, but could be construed as a faint insult when used personally.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE! I agree that `dämlich` would fit. However, it would give the sentences a slightly different meaning than e.g. `albern` in the accepted answer, wouldn't it? Maybe you want to improve your answer by adding some information on how `dämlich` would be understood or when it could or should not be used?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful amendment. I wonder what your literal connotation of "herrlich" might be ;-)

Comment: It is strange that *herrlich* means almost the opposite. The negative meaning of *dämlich* is unfair to *Damen*.

Comment: It is not unfair, it's probably just kind of "etymologigal bad luck". I opened two questions to discuss the relationsips of the two word pairs: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15720/ist-das-adjektiv-dämlich-von-dame-abgeleitet and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15722/ist-das-adjektiv-herrlich-von-herr-abgeleitet

Answer (score 1):

A quite popular word for someone appearing a little dumb but rather in the sense of being confused is „dusselig“. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dusslig

This would fit nicely in the second example sentence.