# Ist das Adjektiv "dämlich" von "Dame" abgeleitet?

Tags: etymology, adjective

In [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-express-silly-in-german/15684#15684) und der darauf folgenden Diskussion kam die Vermutung auf, dass `dämlich` "unhöflicherweise" von `Dame` abgeleitet sein könnte. Ist das tatsächlich der Fall?

---

<sup>Ich habe das gleich selbst recherchiert und eine [überzeugende Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-express-silly-in-german/15684#15684) gefunden, die sowohl `dämlich` als auch `herrlich` behandelt. Ich mache hier zwei Fragen daraus, da es um zwei verschiedene Wörter geht, und übernehme die wichtigsten Punkte, damit sie hier diskutiert werden können. Und vielleicht hat ja sogar jemand noch eine bessere Antwort parat?



Die "Schwesterfrage" findet man [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/15722/9091).</sup>

Comment: Übrigens hat wahrscheinlich der *Damhirsch*, der auch wenig mit der Dame zu tun hat, eine ähnliche Ethymologie.

Comment: Was sollen die Anführungsstriche um "unhöflicherweise" ausdrücken?

Comment: @userunknown In der verlinkten Antwort und den Kommentaren dazu wird diese Herleitung einmal als "unkind" und einmal als "unfair" bezeichnet. Ich nehme mal an, dass ich da vor 3 Jahren sowas wie ein zusammenfassendes Zitat kennzeichnen wollte.

Comment: Die Konstruktion: "Die Vermutung kam auf, dass *dämlich* unhöflicherweise von Dame abgeleitet sein könnte" setzt das *unhöflich* bereits in den Kontext einer an anderer Stelle getätigten Vermutung. Welche Vermutung kam auf? "Die Vermutung, dass ... sein könnte" - der ganze Teilsatz. Anführungsstriche heben das eine Wort optisch aus dieser Konstruktion heraus - nur wohin? Entweder Du schreibst "Merkel hat gesagt, dass Trump stinkt." oder "Merkel sagte: >>Trump stinkt.<<" Aber nicht "Merkel sagte, dass Trump >>stinkt<<". Das macht keinen Sinn.

Comment: @userunknown Wenn Du das diskutieren willst, mach eine Frage dazu auf. Ich will es nicht.

Comment: Ich habe dazu weniger eine Frage, als eine Antwort.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Eine ausführliche Erklärung zur Etymologie liefert auch das [Etymologische Wörterbuch von W. Pfeifer (auf DWDS)](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=d%C3%A4mlich):

> ... germ, *þēm-*, das sich mit aind. *tā́myati* ‘erstickt, wird betäubt’, lat. *tēmētum* ‘berauschendes Getränk’, *tēmulentus* ‘berauscht’, aslaw. *tomiti*, russ. *tomít* (томить) ‘quälen’ auf die Wurzel ie. *tem*- ‘geistig benommen, betäubt’ zurückführen läßt. Letztlich gehört die Wortgruppe wohl zur Wurzel ie. *tem(ə)-* ‘dunkel’ (s. Dämmerung).

Es handelt sich also um einen sehr alten indo-europäischen Wortstamm, der sich in vielen indoeuropäischen Sprachen wiederfindet und der mit den *Damen* nichts gemein hat (dies hat ihre etymologische Wurzel in der lateinischen *domina* und daraus französisch *dame*).

Das ursprünglich germanische *þēm* hat sich allerdings erstaunlicherwiese erst im 18. Jahrhundert mit dem ehemals althochdeutschen Suffix *-līh* *(von Gestalt sein)* zu *dämlich* verknüpft. In Grimm's Wörterbuch ist *dämlich* noch gar nicht gelistet (allerdings dafür das veraltete *[dämisch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GD00309#XGD00309)*).

Comment: Auf Bairisch heißt es bis heute *dammisch*

Comment: Ah, so *dimwitted* would be a rather "etymologically faithful" translation for *dämlich*.

Comment: @kjo: yeah *dimwitted* appears to be of same etymology.

Comment: Das zitierte Wörterbuch ist übrigens Wolfgang Pfeifer: Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen. Akademie Verlag Berlin 1989. DWDS hostet das WB nur.

Comment: Danke, habe das korrigiert.

Answer (score 11):

Die Antwort lautet: "Nein", auch wenn es auf den ersten Blick so aussieht und es sogar mit "nämlich - Name" ein fast gleichlautendes und tatsächlich miteinander verwandtes Wortpaar gibt.

Das Adjektiv „**dämlich**“ gehört zu dem Verb „dämeln“. Es heißt „sich kindisch benehmen“, „verwirrt sein", laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/daemlich): "nicht recht bei Sinnen sein". Der Ursprung liegt wahrscheinlich im Verb „dämmern“. Die Ausgangsbedeutung des Adjektivs „dämlich“ ist etwa „nicht ganz helle“, „taumelig“. Es ist eher ein Schimpfwort wie auch „Däm(e)lack“ (aus der gleichen Grundlage).

Das Substantiv „**Dame**“ hingegen ist eine Entlehnung von italienisch „dama“, spanisch „dama“ und französisch „dame“, die alle auf das lateinische „domina“ (Herrin, Hausherrin) zurückgehen.

Quelle: eine [Antwort von "Albert" bei gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/herrlich-und-daemlich)