# Unterschied zwischen blöd, dumm, dämlich und doof

Tags: word-usage, difference

Was viele Deutschlernende interessieren würde, und was aus einem Wörterbuch nicht unbedingt direkt hervorgeht, wären die subtilen Unterschiede zwischen den Vokabeln *dumm*, *doof*, *blöd* und *dämlich* mit Anwendungsbeispielen.

Insbesondere: welches Adjektiv benutzen wir vorzugsweise, um ausdrücken, dass:

- jemand geistig beschränkt ist
- jemand einfältig/töricht ist
- wir eine Sache ärgerlich finden

etc.

Comment: Warum nur diese drei? Was ist mit *dämlich, bescheuert* und denen, die mir aus dem Stegreif nicht einfallen?

Comment: Bescheuert ist schon etwas fortgeschrittener, aber dämlich (so geschrieben!) ist ein guter Einwand.

Comment: Hoppla, da hätte ich ja fast nähmlich geschrieben … ;)

Comment: Dieses Wort gibt es ebenso wenig :) Es kommt vom "Name", und **nicht** von "nehmen" --> "-nahme" (wie "per Nachnahme schicken"), dementsprechend heißt es **nämlich**.

Comment: For those non-native learners of German: there is this proverb to help students with spelling: *Wer nämlich mit 'h' schreibt ist dämlich*.

Comment: @BarthZalewski Stell dich mal a bissle gräder hin, da is n Witz grad über deinen Kopf hinweggesegelt ;)

Comment: @Jan ok ich habe das Sprichwort nicht gekannt. Deswegen ist mir der Witz entgangen :) Viele Grüße

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Etymologien

**Dämlich** kommt – wie wir alle gewusst haben – nicht von der *Dame*. Wiktionary stellt eine »unklare Etymologie« fest, das [DWDS](http://dwds.de/?qu=d%C3%A4mlich) führt es auf eine altgermanische Wurzel **þem-* zurück, die entsprechend einer protoindogermanischen Wurzel **tem-* sei, und eine Bedeutung *geistig benommen, betäubt* habe – vgl. *tēmētum* (lat, *berauschendes Getränk*), *томить* (russ. *quälen*), *tā́myati* (altindisch *erstickt, wird betäubt*). Im oberdeutschen Sprachraum wird gerne stattdessen *dammisch* verwendet, das lediglich auf einem anderen Suffix beruht.

**Dumm** entstammt der altgermanischen Wurzel **dumbaz*, aus der sich auch das englische *dumb* herausentwickelt hat. Die ursprüngliche Bedetung war *stumm*. (Das Wort *stumm* sieht zwar ähnlich aus, lässt sich aber auf eine andere Wurzel der Bedeutung *gehemmt* zurückverfolgen.) Nahe verwandt ist auch das Wort **doof**, das aus **daubaz* entstandden ist – analog zum englischen *deaf* hat es ursprünglich *taub* bedeutet, und wurde aus dem Niederdeutschen übernommen. Beide entstammen daher, dass die Unfähigkeit zu hören oder zu sprechen mit mangelnder Intelligenz gleichgesetzt wurde.

**Blöd** lässt sich auf protogermanisches **blauþaz* oder **blauþijaz* zurückführen und bezeichnete ursprünglich *schwach, ängstlich*. Von allen hier erfragten Wörtern ist es mir am wenigsten klar, wie daraus die heutige Bedeutung entstehen könnte, denn Ängstlichkeit wird eher selten mit Dummheit gleichgesetzt.

### Benutzung

Die klassische mangelnde Intelligenz würde ich am ehesten mit *dumm* beschreiben.

> Mensch bist du dumm! Das weiß doch jedes Kind, dass zwei und zwei vier ergeben.
>
> »Zwei Dinge sind unendlich – das Universum und die menschliche Dummheit. Aber beim Universum bin ich mir noch nicht ganz sicher« (Albert Einstein zugeschrieben)

Andererseits kann man auch alle anderen Wörter dort vorfinden, und es wirkt nicht falsch.

*Doof* würde ich gleichzeitig für *wenig durchdacht* oder *nicht zuende gedacht* hernehmen.

> Das wäre doch total doof, dann laufen wir direkt in einen Hinterhalt.

*Dämlich* – oder vielmehr *dammisch* – wäre mein klassisches Schimpfwort, wenn mir jemand blöd kommt oder etwas unüberlegtes tun will. Es hängt sich meines Erachtens mehr an Handlungen auf: ich würde eher selten Gedanken oder Aussagen als »dammisch« bezeichnen.

> Bist du dammisch? Du kannst doch ned den heißen Topf so nah an die Kante stellen! Ist doch klar, dass der umfällt.

Zuletzt *blöd*. Das verwende ich am häufigsten für Regeln, die von außen auf mich hereinwirken.

> Die Graduiertenschule kommt immer wieder auf *blöde* Ideen.

---

Das Problem mit allen vier Wörtern ist, dass sie immer in einem Kontext am besten passen, aber wir Muttersprachler selten uns überlegen, *warum* sie dort passen, und *wie* wir diesen Kontext in allgemeingültigere Kategorien pressen könnten.

Zum Beispiel die *blöde Schwester*, die Martin in einem Kommentar erwähnt hat: Sie muss nicht unintelligent sein (das wäre eine *dumme Schwester*) und sie gestellt sich nicht unbedingt sonderlich (das wäre eine *doofe Schwester*) und schon gar nicht macht sie undurchdachte Sachen (… *dammische Schwester*). Vielmehr hat sie ihn mit ihren Puppen und vielleicht auch anderen Spielsachen genervt – das war für mich sofort klar, bevor er die Erklärung dahintergeschrieben hat. Und vielleicht helfen diese vier Kleinbeispiele auch ein wenig bei der Einordnung.

Comment: Siehe auch http://german.stackexchange.com/q/15720/9091

Comment: Das ist so nicht ganz richtig. Es gibt einen Entscheidenden Unterschied zwischen dumm und doof:
Dumm = nicht Wissen
Doof = nicht können
"dumm" ist keine Beleidigung, da es jeder selbst ändern kann (dazu lernen)
"doof" ist eine Beleidigung, da es eine nicht ausreichende Fähigkeit beschreibt, die man nicht einfach so ändern kann (dafür kann's Schmerzensgeld geben)

Comment: "Das wäre doch total dämlich, dann laufen wir ...", "Das wäre doch total dumm, dann laufen wir ..." ... ich denke die 2 sind beliebig austauschbar

Comment: @Sarah Hast du einen Beleg für das Schmerzensgeld?

Answer (score 0):

Da ist kein Unterschied, es sind Varianten für die gleiche Idee. Es gibt bestimmte Adjektivbereiche, die sehr häufig angesprochen werden, wie zB blöd. Es wäre langweilig, wenn wir da immer das gleiche Adjektiv verwenden würden. In solchen Bereichen entwickeln sich immer sehr viele Varianten, in allen Sprachen.

Comment: Würde ich jetzt so nicht unbedingt zu 100% unterschreiben. Ich kann sagen 'Du bist doof!' ohne jemanden damit als 'dumm' zu deklassieren. Oder ich habe eine blöde Schwester, die ich als solche bezeichne, weil sie mich mit ihren Puppen genervt hat. Die Unterschiede sind durchaus subtil, aber mitunter sehr deutlich, wenn im Kontext gelesen.

Comment: Ob diese subtilen Unterschiede, die du als Deutscher in bestimmten Situationen differenzieren kannst, einen Lerner interessieren, würde ich bezweifeln.

Comment: @rogermue Naja, auch wenn es ggfs. in der anderen Sprache auch diese Unterschiede gibt? Ich bin froh den Unterschied zwischen aim, target und goal gelernt zu haben.

Comment: Es gibt eine ganze Menge Adjektivbereiche mit vielen Varianten - 1 Das ist prima/toll/Spitze ... 2 Das ist sclecht. 3 Das ist  blöd. 4 Das ist seltsam.  Und andere.

Answer (score -1):

Über einfältige, beschränkte Menschen kann man alles sagen.

In einer ärgerlichen Situation würde ich auch mit allen Ausdrücken rechnen, außer mit "dämlich", aber ganz ausschließen wollte ich dessen Gebrauch auch nicht ("Wie dumm/blöd/doof dass wir den Anschlusszug verpasst haben!").

Dumm kann am ehesten benutzt werden für jemanden, der etwas nicht weiß, ohne dass man dessen geistigen Fähigkeiten prinzipiell in Frage stellt. 8jährigen, die nicht quadrieren können, sind dumm, weil sie dieses Wissen noch nicht erworben haben - es kommt aber auch in der Schule erst viel später.

Wer einstellige Zahlen mit 16 noch nicht addieren kann, der würde auch blöd/doof/dämlich genannt werden können, aber ein 8jähriger der es nicht kann eher nicht.

Oder jmd. der gelernt hat, dass man Jugendlicher/Erwachsener nicht auf dem Fußweg oder Fußgängerübergang radfahren darf, es aber trotzdem tut - der ist nicht dumm, sondern doof, dämlich und blöd.

Siehe auch [GWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=GWB&lemid=JD02462):

> b unerfahren, ungebildet, unwissend, unreif, roh; bes von
>   Jugendlichen, mehrf ‘d-er Junge, Bube’ u von sozial Niedrigstehenden,
>   mehrf ‘d-es Volk’ uä

Comment: -1 für die dumme Definition von dumm. Wieso sollte ich meinen 3-jährigen Sohn als dumm bezeichnen, nur weil er noch nicht sicher bis zehn zählen, geschweige denn quadrieren kann? Nach der Definition wären wir alle miteinander saudumm, weil jeder von uns sehr, sehr vieles nicht weiß.

Comment: Weil der Begriff nicht nur abwertend verwendet wird. Dumm kann jmd. sein, der vieles noch nicht weiß. Dein 3jähriger Sohn ist ja wahrscheinlich auch klein. So ist das, wenn man noch klein und dumm ist. Blöd ist es, dem Kleinen einen Vorwurf draus zu machen, dass er noch dumm ist. Dämlich ist es auch, sich als 14jähriger was drauf einzubilden nicht so dumm zu sein wie ein 7jähriger.

Comment: Antwort um Zitat ergänzt.