# Ist das Adjektiv "herrlich" von "Herr" abgeleitet?

Tags: etymology, adjective

In [dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-express-silly-in-german/15684#15684) und der darauf folgenden Diskussion kam die Vermutung auf, daß `herrlich` von `Herr` abgeleitet sein könnte (was insbesondere mit Blick auf das Paar `dämlich/Dame` unfair bis sexistisch wirkt). Ist das tatsächlich der Fall?

---

<sup>Ich habe das gleich selbst recherchiert und eine [überzeugende Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/how-to-express-silly-in-german/15684#15684) gefunden, die sowohl `dämlich` als auch `herrlich` behandelt. Ich mache hier zwei Fragen daraus, da es um zwei verschiedene Wörter geht, und übernehme die wichtigsten Punkte, damit sie hier diskutiert werden können. Und vielleicht hat ja sogar jemand noch eine bessere Antwort parat?




Die Schwesterfrage findet man [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15720/ist-das-adjektiv-d%C3%A4mlich-von-dame-abgeleitet).</sup>

Comment: Bei "Herr" muss man aber auch beachten, dass es zwei verschiedene Bedeutungen gibt, die man an der zugehörigen weiblichen Form gut unterscheiden kann: Herr/Frau vs. Herr/Herrin. Wenn "herrlich" von "Herr" abgeleitet sein sollte, dann m.E. von der zweiten Form, und damit wäre es nicht sexistisch, weil da ja auch die weibliche Form das "Herr" enthält.

Comment: Wolfgang Pfeifer weiß es: https://www.dwds.de/wb/herrlich#et-1

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Dann mach eine Antwort daraus.

Comment: @Matthias keine Zeit...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nein, eine direkte Ableitung liegt nicht vor; wohl aber eine Verwandtschaft der beiden Wörter.

Das Adjektiv „**herrlich**“ ist eine Weiterbildung des Adjektivs „[hehr](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hehr)“. Dies stammt von einem germanischen Adjektivwort „haira-“ (grauhaarig, ergraut), dessen Bedeutung zu „ehrwürdig“ weiterentwickelt wurde (die Haare als ehrfurchtgebietendes Statussymbol) und danach zu „vornehm“, „von hohem Rang“, „erhaben“.

Das Substantiv „**Herr**“ ist eine Substantivierung des Adjektivs "hehr", gebildet aus dem Komparativ des althochdeutschen „hêriro“ („der Hehrere/Höhere/Höhergestellte“). Wahrscheinlich ist eine Anlehnung an das lateinische „senior“ („der Ältere“). In Komposita (Wortzusammensetzungen) stand „Herren-“ eigentlich für „den Herren (Adligen) vorbehalten“, dann häufig für „besser“, „hochstehend“.

Das Adjektiv „herrlich“ hat also die gleiche Wurzel wie das Substantiv „Herr“, ist aber nicht davon abgeleitet. Allerdings ist früh eine Verbindung gezogen worden, und dieser Bezug hat in den Wortbedeutungen von „herrlich“ abgefärbt (mit Abwandlungen zu Bedeutungen wie „prächtig“, „unübertrefflich gut und schön“). Darin steckt aber keine Huldigung an Männer allgemein, sondern an gesellschaftlich hochgestellte Menschen.

Quelle: eine [Antwort von "Albert" bei gutefrage.net](http://www.gutefrage.net/frage/herrlich-und-daemlich)

Answer (score 1):

Ohne jetzt so schöne Herleitungen wie Matthias bieten zu können ... ich habe noch einen zweiten Vorschlag.

Ich bin immer davon ausgegangen, dass das sehr wohl an das Wort "Herr" angelehnt ist - also natürlich auch an "hehr" - aber nicht im gesellschaftlichen, sondern im religiösen Sinne. So, als wolle man ausdrücken, dass sich Gottes Werk in der so bezeichneten Sache besonders schön zeigt, oder dass etwas von so großer Güte ist, dass es wohl Gottes besonderer Wille sein muss.

Das finde ich insofern einleuchtend, als dass man etwas nicht als "herrlich" bezeichnet, wenn es nicht etwas wirklich und ursprünglich Positives beinhaltet, das einen einfach wegen seiner Existenz mit Zufriedenheit erfüllt. Eine herrliche Aussicht zum Beispiel, herrliches Wetter oder ein herrliches Erlebnis. Da der christliche Glaube in den heute deutschsprachigen Landen lange Zeit das Gesellschaftsbild geprägt hat, kann ich mir diese Herkunft mindestens ebenso gut vorstellen.

"Herrlich" in Bezug auf den Gesellschaftsstatus "Herrschaft" (geschlechtsneutral) hätte für mich sogar eine Assoziation von Weltlichkeit, Geld und sogar potentiellem Neid, die ich in der Verwendung des Wortes nicht wirklich entdecken kann.

Comment: Klingt schön, aber ich habe Zweifel: Laut meiner Quelle gab es das Wort „hêrlîch“ schon im 11. Jh. Damit das Argument funktioniert, müßte die Bedeutung "Herr" für "Gott" _in diesem Wortstamm_ bis in diese Zeit zurückreichen. Bin da wahrlich kein Experte, aber soweit ich verstanden habe, ist das althochdeutsche Wort für "Herr" im Sinne von "Gott" jedoch "truhtīn". - Abgesehen davon könnte es natürlich sein, daß der spätere Gebrauch des Wortes von solchen Überlegungen beeinflußt wurde, d.h. es wäre zwar nicht das Wort selbst, aber seine heutige Bedeutung zumindest teilweise so erklärbar.

Comment: Interessant! Wie kommt es, dass sich zwar das Konzept "Gott" in der Sprache erhalten hat, aber von dem Wort "truhtīn" nichts mehr übrig geblieben ist? Außer vielleicht "trauen"? (OT, ich weiß :) )

Comment: Reine Spekulation, daher -1